# read many rfid tags in close proximity

Tags: count, rfid

There is a passive RFID tag, containing the UPC code, attached to a screw driver. If there are 100 of these screw drivers with the same UPC code packed in a box, can a RFID reader accurately count the 100 pieces?

Comment: I don't think this is about coding or software.

Answer (score -1):

I have not selected a scanner. I can go with whichever would give an accurate reading.

Comment: Are you the same person that asked for an answer?